Does religion put people in a disadvantage in this life (wordly success) in return for a succeessful afterlife?
For example check this hadith out,

"Whoever focuses on only one concern, the afterlife, Allah will be enough for his concerns in the world. Whoever scatters his concerns among the matters of the world, it does not matter to Allah in which valley he meets his demise." Az-Zuhd li-Ibn Abi Asim (161), graded Hasan in As-Sahihah (7/349-50 - #3287)

As per this hadith, the focus on afterlife is more than sufficient. Then can someone explain to me where in the entire Islamic literature does it say how to perform surgery or medicine or other important aspects of human civilization?
according to this hadith does investing oneself in a noble career like Medicine inherently bad? because the hadith encourages to focus only on the afterlife.

The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "When Allah loves a servant, he protects them from the world, just as one of you keeps the sick from drinking too much water."At-Tirmidhi (2036) noted as Sahih by Shaykh Albani


Please keep questions focused to be clearly answerable. If you're looking for open-ended discussion, take it to [chat].

@goldPseudo got you. Thank you for the suggestion.
